# Using labview dll in visual studio: how to overcome "Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'"

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015, labview

I want to control Microsoft Visual Studio to use the dll which generated from labview. I have some problems here. I use labview 2017 and visual studio 2015.

- 1. I create a test project and I create a math.vi to do mathematics addition. Then I use Build Specifications under project to create shared library.
- 2. I create a win32 console application in visual studio and create a math project:

> project -> properties -> configuration properties -> vc++ directories -> include directories: C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2017\cintools was added
>
> move SharedLib.lib to ...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\math\math
>   project -> properties -> configuration properties -> vc++ directories -> library directories: Visual Studio 2015\Projects\math\math was added
>
> project -> properties -> configuration properties -> Linker -> Input -> Addtional Dependencies: SharedLib.lib was added
>
> move the ShareLib. h to ...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\math\math and add it from header files in solution 'math'

- 3. motify the math.cpp file

  ```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "SharedLib.h"
   int main()
   {
      double k = Math(3.2, 4.5);
      return 0;
   }
  ```

It could successfully compiled by visual studio and then I move the dll file under ...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\math\math.

But, when I build it, it give me the following error:

> Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' math D:\Wenxu Documents\My Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\math\math\SharedLib.lib 1 
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _Math referenced in function _main math d:\wenxu documents\my documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\math\math\math.obj 1 
>   Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals math d:\wenxu documents\my documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\math\Debug\math.exe 1**

All files are attached. I am pretty new to labview. Thanks for your help very much! I was confused on it for a couple days. I appreciate a lot if you could give me some hints.

Comment: I don't know much about C++ or Visual Studio but `library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'` sounds like a 64-vs-32-bit problem to me. At a guess you need to change something about the Visual Studio project to match the 32- or 64-bit status of the DLL you built in LabVIEW.

Comment: Thank you very much! I fix it by redo all things in labview 32 bits instead of 64 bits. It seems that labview 64 is not fully supported.